# Delete records from table using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm very new to ModelBuilder so forgive me if there is a relatively simple tool to perform this. I have looked into Delete Field/Table but it does not seem to achieve the goal.

Goal: Create a tool that will update the master parcel feature class on one geoDB with combined data from a feature class and table in another location.

How do I go about deleting the data that is in the master parcel feature class without deleting the headers? I basically want it to be a blank template with headers to later append/join the newest information with. Or would it be simpler to delete the file and just save the joined information in its place?

I'm also not sure if I have permissions to delete files, only modify, so finding a way to go about this without deleting would be great.

---

edit:

I realize that I may have have explained this poorly. Our master parcel feature class is the result of a manual combination of a geometry feature class and a parcel data table that is provided by our county assessor office. The goal of the tool would be to automate this process.

My current workflow:
BlountParcels - Master Parcel feature class (what needs to be updated/overwritten)
Parcels - Geometry feature class
camagisdata - table parcel data

[image]

Comment: Why not just delete all the features in the feature class? Then you still have your fields schema, but the feature class is empty? Not sure if that is your goal though. The Append tool might be an alternative.

Comment: Have you considered adding new fields and calculating values within the new fields?  You can always delete old fields later.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you should try the [**Delete Rows**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n6000000) tool.

Comment: If you are using 10.1, you can also use [**Truncate Table**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000016z000000).  Delete Rows honors selection sets, but with Truncate table, _If a selection is applied to a layer or table view, the selection will be ignored—all records will be truncated._